# Reading huge data from files and calling them

Tags: python

I am creating a program that reads x,y,z in the format of (1.000 2.000 3.000), first coloumn is x second is y and the third is z. I would like to read this data from this file (hiz.txt) and then call up on them as variables later on. I am looking for about 50-100 rows of this data, and i want my program to keep looking and transferring until it reaches the end.

Comment: So learn to program, then try to write the program, then if you get stuck come back and we'll help you.

Answer (score 2):

I assume by "huge data" you mean the file won't all fit into memory, so you have to go line by line.

I also assume you just want to save up the 50 or so rows you are looking for and that those *will* fit into memory.

So Like this:

```
theDataIWant = []

def isThisSomethingIWant(x, y, z):
    return the condition involving ... x ... y ... z ...

for line in open('myfile','r'):
    x, y, z = line.split(" ")
    if isThisSomethingIWant(x, y, z):
        theDataIWant.append( (x, y, z) )
```

Comment: -1. This answer is unhelpful because there is no good way to answer this question. He wants code written for him but doesn't provide enough info to actually do it.

Comment: Respectfully disagree.  I am giving the benefit of the doubt to the OP and assuming he or she is asking a legitimate question about "huge data" and has trouble phrasing a question about how to process a file without reading the whole thing into memory.  Lots of questions are well-intentioned though poorly worded. I could very well be wrong though about the OP intentions, so I don't object to the downvote. :)

Comment: @agf Dude, downvotes are for answers that are wrong and misleading; if it's only vague (because the question happens to be so), do us all a favour and don't punish someone's good intentions. Just leave it at "0".

Comment: @MaDa Mouse over the downvote button. "This answer is not useful". I'm pretty sparing with my downvotes, feel free to check my profile. Less than 10% of my votes are downvotes, and most of those are on questions. But this is not a question it's possible to answer usefully, and posting something like this is a waste of everyone's time. No one is helped, and it encourages bad questions.

Comment: @agf I see your point.  My first thought was "benefit of the doubt" and the "OP's English isn't great", but I see the OP posted the exact same question twice more and hasn't started any coding this at all -- yet got similar answers. So yes it looks like there is a problem with encouragement.  It was kinda hard to tell at first, though.... Live and learn.