# Searching through file (Python)

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading huge data from files and calling them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940467/reading-huge-data-from-files-and-calling-them)

I want to read through an input(text file) and the format for this text file is `2.000 3.000 4.000` , now i want to assign `2.000` to be x and `3.000` to be y and `4.000` to be z. The problem is that I will be searching through the entire file which might have 50-60 lines of the data. I am not sure how to assign the values to the certain variables and I'm also not sure on how to search through the file until there is no more data.

Answer (score 2):

Read the file line-by-line, split the line into components, and then make each component a `float` so that you can use it as a number instead of a string:

```
handle = open('myfile.txt', 'r')

for line in handle:
  x, y, z = map(float, line.split(' '))

  print 'x is', x
  print 'y is', y
  print 'z is', z
  print

handle.close()
```

Now `x`, `y`, and `z` hold the three values for each loop.

If you're working with strictly integers, replace `float` with `int`.

Answer (score 0):

In python there is a fairly easy way to do that:

```
f = open('filename')
for line in f:
   # assuming all lines have almost the same format
   (x, y, z) = line.split()
f.close()
```

Comment: How should I do this for the other lines, since I have 50 lines that have listed the same format but different values

Comment: It would be best to have a repeating output, read in the x,y,z and then doing that over and over again