# Search through file until no more data

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reading huge data from files and calling them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940467/reading-huge-data-from-files-and-calling-them)

I do not know how to search through a file, I have a file which has around 50 lines of data in this format (1.000 2.000 3.000) but I do not know how to do one line do a conversion(already have) then go to the next line do the same until it reaches the end, so basically do a process line by line until no more lines.

Comment: Please don't post a new question to clarify your previous one. Just edit the old one to be clearer / to provide more info

Comment: To whoever upvoted this an the previous, duplicate question -- under what possible interpretation is this question useful or clear, or does it show research effort?

Answer (score 5):

```
with open('filename') as f:
  for line in f:
    line = line.rstrip()
    # do the conversion (that you already know how to do)
```

Here:

1. `with open('filename') as f:` opens the file (and automatically closes it at the end);
2. `for line in f:` reads every line of the file into `line`;
3. `line = line.rstrip()` removes any trailing whitespaces and the newline character from `line`.

Comment: As a side note to user1020048: when using the _with_ statement you need not close the file not use a try/finally block to ensure the file gets closed. If you do not use the _with_ statement but use something like f = open('file') you should use try/finally and f.close().